# regarding multilanguage URL rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, multilingual

I wanna implement url rewriting so that, for example, all german pages have a url with /de/ after the domain name (and english pages with an /en/) but I don't actually have to create and manage all those subdirectories. I want this "de"/en to persist through out the website

Just like mentioned in the article below:-

http://www.deevelop.com/en/web-design-company/blog/12/Multilingual-website.html

Please check the content under "SUBDIRECTORIES" heading in this article.

This article doesn't explain stuff in detail. Can I please have  link to more such examples that are elaborative enough?

Or if someone has implemented such a thing may help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL rewriting is the process of intercepting an incoming Web request and redirecting the request to a different resource. When performing URL rewriting, typically the URL being requested is checked and, based on its value, the request is redirected to a different URL. For example, in the case where a website restructuring caused all of the Web pages in the /people/ directory to be moved to a /info/employees/ directory, you would want to use URL rewriting to check if a Web request was intended for a file in the /people/ directory. If the request was for a file in the /people/ directory, you'd want to automatically redirect the request to the same file, but in the /info/employees/ directory instead.

You first need to download SP1(free) and install it, then follow these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.01.extremeaspnet.aspx

http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/